# ISL Light macOS remote connection via SSH

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, ssh

I am trying to establish a new tunnel on ISL Light app from [ISL Online](https://www.islonline.com/). I have an account already and on when I log in, in the Computers window I can access a remote server that I am assigned to have access to. The thing is I am trying to connect to it with my MacBook Pro M2 2022 but I am not able to do so.

I have tried with different commands as the SSH default schema as follows:

- `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ssh -p {PORT} myusername@localhost"'`
  This is the main one I have tried, changing app for application, and neither of those works. The thing with this one is that the tunnel is opened I suppose because on ISL Light I can see that I have an opened connection to the remote server but the Terminal app does not open so I cannot access via SSH to the remote server.
- `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "ssh -p {PORT} myusername@localhost" in front window'`
  Looking for possible solutions I found this but it does not work either.
- `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate'`
  This one gave an error that the parameter {PORT} was missing.
  I would like to know if there is a problem with compatibility with ISL Light or with my command to open the terminal on Mac OS. I have contacted the ISL Light support center but got nothing solved.

Comment: Why do you want to use `osascript` here? Can't you just open Terminal manually and run `ssh ...`? Also, if you need this for work, aren't you entitled to support by ISL?

Comment: Also, after looking at some of the videos from ISL: this seems to be a remote *desktop* solution, what do you need ssh for here?